# Is it possible to ask procurement questions for newbies?

Tags: discussion

I've been asked to come up with a 'clean slate' hardware recommendation despite having very little knowledge of hardware for an application server and a database server?  I have to 'find' all the hardware on this government pricing site:
http://www.gsaadvantage.gov

Does anyone know of a way to just get a Good, Better, Best general purpose 'stack' without having to put too much effort to it just to get a conversation going with the vendor to see if the software can run on it?

Comment: I always feel sorry for people dumped into the situation you're in but Jeff raises the central problem with these questions: If you don't know what you need then we cannot help you figure it out within the reasonable boundaries of this site. There isn't any "general purpose" spec you can use - You mention database servers - I've built several database servers for my employer. Some of them are similar (some of them are identical!) but some of them are also very different. It varies due to requirements and there isn't an off the peg solution.

Comment: For this kind of situation it's pretty pointless asking us. Get in touch with one of the many companies that specialise in helping people make intelligent decisions about server room purchases. If you don't know how to find those companies you might start by finding the partners on the hardware manufacturers web sites.

Answer (score 12):

Sorry, no :(

We can't judge your needs without a lot of detail. Since you don't know a lot, we'd have to ask a lot. That's bleeding into the realm of consulting. I do that, but it takes hours and I charge for it (for huge projects, it could takes weeks or longer and involve testing samples!). It's definitely not suited for chat.

This won't be something that easily carries over to others who are looking for help, so it's not appropriate for the main site either.

Basically, I'm sorry to say, we just don't have a home for that kind of research.

You might be able to learn something from watching [talks from things like the LISA events](http://static.usenix.org/events/lisa11/tech/), but in all reality if you have this as a job requirement and you're in over your heard, your employer either needs to train you or hire somebody (consultant or staff) who can cover it.

Comment: +1 "if you have this as a job requirement and you're in over your heard, your employer either needs to train you or hire somebody (consultant or staff) who can cover it."